# How to best mix Godox Strobes with legacy Bowens Strobe?

Tags: wireless-flash, wireless-triggers, strobes, wireless, godox

I recently co-rented a studio which has an assortment of studio strobes (Bowens Gemini GM500R, Bowens GM750+). However I usually use my Godox AD600BM and 2 AD200.

**Mixing the strobes**

From what I see, the Bowens strobes have a 5mm sync input jack. So I would need some receiver that has a cable sync output that can be hooked up with the bowens strobes. This probably would be the Godox X1R (no matter which flavour (C, N, S), as I will only need the sync port). They are around 40 Euro a piece. I would probably need around 3. This seems a bit expensive for using only the sync signal of them.

Is there any cheaper way or better way? Using the X2 trigger, I could mount a system neutral trigger on top of it. However, in that case I would lose the ability to switch the strobes into groups and disable them remotely while I am testing the settings.

Is there any recommendation either to controlling them directly with the Godox trigger or good options with an off-brand one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the X1R, there is the US$25 [Flashpoint R2 SPT](http://flashhavoc.com/flashpoint-r2-spt-single-firing-pin-transceivers-released/) single-pin transceiver. However, because this is an Adorama exclusive, *if you're outside the US, it's not really an option.*

If you're willing to swap the transmitter, too, you could consider the [Yongnuo RF-605 transceivers](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-rf605-flash-trigger-announced/), which allow for group on/off control, but they don't do remote power control.

That, or give up group on/off control and just use the built in optical triggering on the Bowens strobes.

Comment: If one needs multiples of the Flashpoint R2 SPT, they're also available in pairs for - whelp - they used to be about $32/pair. Now it seems they're exactly twice the price of the single unit. :-( In the long term, you might also find having a couple of X1R units around rather handy for other situations.

Comment: @MichaelC, you did note the OP mentioned prices in euros, right? Access to the SPT is likely to be very limited or twice as expensive as US prices (due to VAT, etc), making the X1R the more economic choice, anyway.

Comment: Yes, I did notice. But aren't answers supposed to be for anyone who might come along later and have the same question (and just *maybe* live in the USA)? My comment was not meant as a criticism to your answer, but rather as supplemental information. Perhaps in the future the pairs will once again be less than two of the singles? Pricing at Adorama is constantly in flux. At times Adorama will have two different listings, with two significantly different prices, for the same exact product. I've noticed that "promotions" in emails with links will lead to the higher priced listings!

Comment: The Flashpoint receiver were what I hoped to find. But as I don't live in the US, I will either head for a 3rd Party one, or check if anyone I know happens to be in NY someone soon and grab a bunch of them. Postage to Germany sadly is outrageous. I once ordered at Adorama before.

Comment: I now settled for a cheap set of Godox DM-16 plus 4 receivers. I will lose group control, but if I find that too much of a hassle to being able to control the flash intensity, I will just donate the trigger to the studio. ;o)

Comment: @KaiMattern, I've never seen those; cool that they run off the strobe's AC power line. They look like 433 MHz manual triggers. I've updated my answer to include the Yongnuo RF-605, which didn't occur to me, since my head kind of locked into Godox stuff.

Comment: Them using the ac line without the need for further batteries appealed to me. These buggers are always flat, when you need them.